# Properly close the window using mouse in Ursina

Tags: python, window, mouse, ursina

For the past couple of days, I have been playing around in the [Ursina Engine in Python](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina), used for creating both 3D and 2D games. But the recurring problem I have been facing with this engine when making 3D games, is that I can't close the window properly. This is happening because mouse is being used inside of the game, to control the player, so if I try to go to the close button, the mouse will always stay in the game. The workaround for this is to move to a different window, position the mouse so it's outside of the window, and then finally hit the close button. But this is a lot of work for the user to do, to simply close the window.

Here is some simple code to demonstrate:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
import random

game = Ursina()

class Block(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(parent = scene, position = position, model = 'cube', color = color.white)

for z in range(20):
    for x in range(20):
        block = Block(position = (x, 0, z))

player = FirstPersonController()
game.run()
```

I believe this import statement is causing this:

`from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController`

How can I close the window properly in Ursina?

Comment: I would create close button inside game - directly in game or as `Quit` in some menu.

Answer (score 6):

One solution to this problem would be to create a way for you to exit the game by pressing a key.

```
def input(key):
    if key == 'escape':
        quit()
```

With this code you can close the game by pressing 'escape'.

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution, Shift+Q (if the exit_button is enabled).

Usually in first person shooters you make a pause menu and put an exit button there. The FirstPersonController hides the mouse cursor and locks the position to the center of the screen. To reverse this, do:

```py
mouse.locked = False
mouse.visible = True
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually press the "Windows" key. Pressing this button open the windows menu, but it also makes the mouse visible.

Another tip, you can put:

```
window.exit_button.visible = False
```

In your code to make it easier to close the window.

Comment: Firstly, I am not on windows. I am on mac. I know it doesn't say compatible on mac in the docs, but somehow I tried it anyway, and it worked. Second, I am getting the following error: `AttributeError: 'Ursina' object has no attribute 'exit_button'`

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you then :(

Answer (score -1):

Just disable the FPC (First Person Controller)
`player.disable()`

**or just**

make the mouse unlocked `mouse.locked = False`, so it can move