# How to catch a mouse in Ursina

Tags: python, game-development, ursina

I'm creating a game using the Ursina engine. In which I use FPS Controller. Which deactivates the mouse pointer. But at the same time I would need to use the mouse in inventory, for example. Is there a way to solve this? What I was looking for on the internet so I found various tips, but rather to hide the mouse pointer.

Comment: please provide a minimal code example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597502/properly-close-the-window-using-mouse-in-ursina/69647257#69647257

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to disable First Person Controller in ursina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161918/how-to-disable-first-person-controller-in-ursina)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to deactivate first person controller.

**Change player to your `fps controller` variable** | `player = FirstPersonController()` |

.

`player.enabled = False`

https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html#FirstPersonController

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
mouse.locked = False
mouse.visible = True
```